# An Algorithm for solving linear inequalities with two variables

Tags: algorithm, math, linear-programming, numerical-methods

I am trying to find an algorithm to determine existence of **strictly positive** integral solutions for a set of linear inequalities with two variables and the following form:

- <sub>1</sub> + <sub>1</sub> ≤ <sub>1</sub>
- <sub>2</sub> + <sub>2</sub> ≤ <sub>2</sub>
- <sub>3</sub> + <sub>3</sub> ≤ <sub>3</sub>
- ...

The problem also involves a final inequality of the following form:

- +  ≥

Some linear programming techniques should work here, and I am not well versed in them. I have been looking for a more adhoc solution, perhaps exploiting the nature and constraints (types of inequality) given in the problem. Any insight or algorithm would be welcome, but something deterministic and linear in terms of , where  is the number of inequalities, would be particularly interesting.

**Additional constraint:** , ,  > 0

Comment: If there are only two variables, then I think you just want `x` and `y` everywhere, not `x1`, `x2`, etc. And is it safe to say that all the numbers involved (`ai`, `bi`, `li`, `x`, `y`) are greater than 0?

Comment: Oh, you are right, sorry. Although, yes all ai's, bi's, li's are greater than 0.

Comment: Ok, so `x` and `y` can be any integer, including 0 and negative integers?

Comment: Technically, but note the final inequality and the constraint on li, as implies that solution has to greater than 0, but yes it can technically be any integer.

Comment: Well, if `bn` is 1, and all the other `b`s are large numbers, then it might be beneficial to use a negative `y`. For example, consider `2x + 10y < 20` and `3x + y > 50`. That has no solution where both `x` and `y` are greater than 0, but it's easily solved with a negative `y`, e.g. `x=20` and `y= -4`.

Comment: I made a quite tragic typo, OOOPS. Updated the question.

Comment: There might be infinite solutions. Is there some expression to optimise (maximise, minimise)?

Comment: Wow. Ok. At least now we know what the question is, lol. That still doesn't force `x` and `y` to both be positive.

Comment: @trincot The goal is to find whether a solution exists or not, no need to find an actual solution.

Comment: @user3386109 I have been having way too many brain hicupps and somehow short circuited for a moment there to think the constraints imply that. I have updated the question with the constraint of finding existence of only positive integeral solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first −1 inequalities describe lines with a negative slope. In other words, they are of the form =+ where  is a negative rational number (this follows from , ,  > 0), and they exclude the area "above" them.

The last inequality describes a line at 45° with negative slope (-1), and it excludes the area "below" it.

We could picture an example problem like this:
[image]

The white area contains the solution points. The dark area is excluded by the −1 first constraints, the violet area is excluded by the last constraint, and the purple areas exclude solutions with a negative  or .

As the slopes of the orange lines are guaranteed to be negative, we can conclude that if there is no point on the last line (the dark red one with slope -1) that belongs to the solution, there is no other point either. There is no way another point could be in the solution while the points on the last (dark red) line would *all* be excluded.

So, we "only" need to check the integer points **on** the last line. In other words, we can replace the final constraint with:

+  =

We can iterate all other constraints and see how the corresponding line's slope compares to the slope of the last line:

- If less than: the orange line is more "horizontal" than the last line. The crossing with the last line represents a lower bound for  (and upper bound for ).
- If greater than: the orange line is more "vertical" than the last line. The crossing with the last line represents an upper bound for  (and lower bound for ).
- If equal: the orange line is parallel to the last line. If it is above the last line (or equal to it), it can be ignored. If it is below the last line, there is no solution.

At the end of this process we have a maximum lower bound and minimum upper bound for . If these (rational) bounds still allow for a positive integer  solution and for which the corresponding  would also be positive, then report a success. Otherwise there is no solution.

This algorithm has a O() time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness I show a traditional linear-programming solution. Advantages are that it's quite easy to construct. Disadvantage is that, while it will be efficient, it won't likely be as efficient as if you fished around in the problem for a manual, analytic or semi-analytic solution.

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng
from scipy.optimize import milp, Bounds, LinearConstraint, OptimizeResult


def solve(ab: np.ndarray, l: np.ndarray) -> OptimizeResult:
    lb = np.full(n+1, -np.inf)  # No lower bounds...
    lb[-1] = l[-1]              # except for the last constraint
    ub = np.full_like(lb, np.inf)  # Default: no upper bounds (for last constraint)
    ub[:-1] = l                    # Most upper bounds determined by 'l'
    A = np.ones((n+1, 2))  # For last constraint: coefficients are 1
    A[:-1, :] = ab         # All other coefficients are 'ab'

    return milp(
        c=np.zeros(2),                 # no optimisation, only bounds-testing
        integrality=np.ones(2),        # x, y both integral
        bounds=Bounds(lb=1),           # only a lower simple bound, of 1
        constraints=LinearConstraint(lb=lb, A=A, ub=ub),
    )


def explain(ab: np.ndarray, l: np.ndarray) -> None:
    a, b = ab.T
    print('a =', a)
    print('b =', b)
    print('l =', l)
    result = solve(ab, l)
    print(result.message)
    if result.success:
        print('x, y =', result.x)
        print('[a b][x y] =', ab @ result.x)
        print('          <=', l)
        print(f'x + y = {result.x.sum()} >= {l[-1]}')
    print()


# Infeasible example
rand = default_rng(seed=1)
n = 6
abl = rand.uniform(low=0.1, high=1, size=(n, 3))
ab = abl[:, :2]
explain(ab, l=abl[:, 2])

# Feasible example
explain(ab, l=ab @ (10, 10))
```

```
a = [0.56063946 0.9537845  0.84493233 0.1248032  0.39675854 0.5081481 ]
b = [0.95541733 0.38064831 0.46827922 0.7781618  0.80958583 0.22063753]
l = [0.22974365 0.4809938  0.59463432 0.58432898 0.37287535 0.46280169]
The problem is infeasible. (HiGHS Status 8: model_status is Infeasible; primal_status is At lower/fixed bound)

a = [0.56063946 0.9537845  0.84493233 0.1248032  0.39675854 0.5081481 ]
b = [0.95541733 0.38064831 0.46827922 0.7781618  0.80958583 0.22063753]
l = [15.16056789 13.34432809 13.13211557  9.02965    12.06344378  7.28785628]
Optimization terminated successfully. (HiGHS Status 7: Optimal)
x, y = [7. 1.]
[a b][x y] = [4.87989356 7.05713982 6.38280556 1.65178421 3.58689565 3.77767423]
          <= [15.16056789 13.34432809 13.13211557  9.02965    12.06344378  7.28785628]
x + y = 8.0 >= 7.287856280550347
```